# Why the GE0 have two ports? what's the difference between them?

Tags: router

Why the GE0 have two ports? what's the difference between them?

[image]

Device: Quidway AR2220.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 'combo' port that can work either as optical (left) or copper Ethernet (right). Usually the extra port is actually a [slot for an SFP module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_form-factor_pluggable_transceiver) (sometimes called a "mini-GBIC") and can accept several different kinds of interfaces – various optical, coaxial, even the regular Ethernet.

In your picture, the port on the left appears to be the correct size for an SFP slot, but it's already got a module for uh, *something*, in it. (Maybe they wanted to depict a module with a single SC optical connection, or some other connector type that I have no clue about?)